# I cannot access to dynamic object properties in Razor Template

Tags: .net, dynamic, razor

I created a dynamic object like below:

```
dynamic myObject = new
{
    DisplayName = "Mahesh"
}; 



Content = Parse("Main", myObject);
```

[image: debug section]

Then I parsed it for Razor template. But it doesnt work because of the object cannot access to its properties. What is the problem here ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous type has some accessibility issues, in that `dynamic` *via the c# provider* tries to respect accessibility. An anonymous type in a different module is *not* accessible (and remember that MVC pages will typically compile into a different module), hence no properties.

IIRC, however, this is actually fixed in a later MVC patch - I seem to remember hitting this when my local machine was a rev higher than our dev-server, meaning: it worked locally on the higher revision, but failed as you describe on the dev-server.

The `ExpandoObject` does not suffer this because it does not use the c# provider (it implements `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` instead), and has no concept of accessibility (it simply maps member-names to the dictionary).

Answer (score 3):

I did it by this way and it works. But I want to know why the way I did first is not working

```
dynamic FooterModel = new ExpandoObject();
FooterModel.DisplayName= "Kaplan";
```

Comment: It would be better if you updated your question to say "However `ExpandoObject` works".

Comment: @Justin actually, I could go either way there - since `ExpandoObject` is *also* an answer to "how can I make this work?". My *preferred* optional personally is to declare a view-model class formally.